# how do i delete or rename a step function execution in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

we use step functions heavily - they are great - they mean that if something fails - we can fix the code or manually fix the input and then re-run it without a client ever being aware something went wrong.

So - we see failed executions as sort of like a "todo" - they don't happen very often - so when an alert tells us something failed, we bring it up, work out what to do to fix it - and fix it.

But obviously - the old failure just hangs around.   Still looking like a todo.

In the perfect world, we'd like to archive it - make it go away somewhere so it's just not in the list, but we can get at it if we wanted to.

Failing that - we'd like to delete it.

Failing that - even being able to rename it from x to [FIXED] x would help.

**NOTE** - *deleting the whole step function isn't an option - we just want to address a single execution.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's currently no way for StepFunctions to edit nor delete an execution.

If it helps, you could filter the list by status "Success" (just for aesthetics), but I know this doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: thanks - that's what my googling told me - but I was hoping someone on stack overflow would have a better answer.    Oh well - writing a chrome extension that will pretend to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can now recover a failed step function.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-step-functions-redrive-a-new-way-to-restart-workflows